# Does Firebase 3.7.0 support in iOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase in my app. I have installed via the Cocoapods. To make support for push notification in iOS 10 I have updated the cocoa pods with the latest version of Firebase 3.7.0.
Please let me know does it support in iOS 7 and iOS 8.

Registeration of push notification like this

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(
    authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_,_ in })

  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
  // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
  FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
  UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Thanks

Comment: yes ... it supports

Comment: Ok thanks, So If I need to support push notification only from the FCM not from the native APNS. Then don't I need to update my registration for push notifications for iOS 10.

Comment: registration ... for what???

Comment: To get push notifcations we need to register push notifications in AppDelegate class according to iOS versions. I am talking about this.

Comment: I have update my question with the registeration method.

Comment: no ... there is nothing to change ... still you can check firebase doc for messaging

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, thanks.